# How to find default Icons on Windows 10 for Toolbar of WPF app?

Tags: wpf, windows-10, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

The `Editing Commands` section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview) Microsoft Documentation on `WPF` shows a toolbar on top of `RichTextBox` with default icons for `Bullets, Numbering, Indents etc`. But the documentation does not describe where those icons are located on the system. When I copy their `XAML` on my project, it gives the error shown below. **Question**: How can I find out those icons (shown in their image below) on my `Windows 10`?

**Error** [screenshot of XAML page on my project. Click the image to get better view]:

[image]

**Image from the [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview)**:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The image patch should use a slash (/) not a backslash ().
Images should be in a Images fold under your project root directory.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="RichTextBoxInputPanelDemo.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="400" Width="600"
>
  <Grid>

    <!-- Set the styles for the tool bar. -->
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatTextStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Palatino Linotype"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value ="14"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="formatImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=mainRTB}"></Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">

      <!-- This tool bar contains all the editing buttons. -->
      <ToolBar Name="mainToolBar" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

        <Button Style="{StaticResource formatImageStyle}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" ToolTip="Cut">
          <Image Source="Images/EditCut.png"></Image>
        </Button>


      </ToolBar>

      <!-- By default pressing tab moves focus to the next control. Setting AcceptsTab to true allows the 
           RichTextBox to accept tab characters. -->
      <RichTextBox Name="mainRTB" AcceptsTab="True"></RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @je The `XAML` shown in my post is from official Microsoft article also linked in my post above. Moreover, the image path in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_image.htm) online tutorial is also showing the backward slash `(\)`. So, path formation does not seem to be a problem. Do you happen to know where can I get those icon images from my `Windows 10` system. Currently I don't have those images in my `VS2017` project.

Comment: Oh, I have never used backslash. Let me know if it works. For icon images, you can get them from Flaticon. They have all the icons you need.https://www.flaticon.com/

Comment: @nam if you found this helpful, please upvote and mark it as answered. Thanks